# Выполнение JavaScript`а при загрузке содержимого через ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем привет! Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией. Есть лента новостей, которая при первоначальной загрузке страницы содержит 7 новостей, остальные подгружаются ajax`ом, также по 7 за раз. После каждой пятой новости нужно разместить баннер, который загружается через javaScript. С первым блоком проблем нет, но в те что подгружаются после баннер вставить не получается, вижу просто пустую страницу. То же самое происходит, если JS тупо вставить в HTML через firebug. Как правильно поступить в этой ситуации? и возможно ли в таком случае исполнение скрипта?

Comment: Через колбэк уже не катит что-ли? И вообще код покажите, как вы это делаете. И почему бы не вставить этот баннер еще на сервере, на стадии формирования ответа на запрос. Зачем делать еще один ajax-запрос ради одного баннера?

Comment: Заходим на страницу, видим 7 новостей. Кликаем "Смотреть еще", подгружаются ещё 7, среди них должен быть баннер. Ajax`ом возвращается html, который содержит скрипт баннера. Но так не катит, страница просто висит. Код вида 
(function(L){if(typeof(ar_cn)=="undefined")ar_cn=1;
   var S='setTimeout(function(e){if(!self.CgiHref){document.close();e=parent.document.getElementById("ar_container_"+ar_bnum);
............
marginheight=0 scrolling=no frameborder=0><\/iframe><\/div><div id="ad_ph_'+ar_cn
     +'" style="display:none;"><\/div>');_();ar_cn++;
   })('http://ad.adriver.ru/cgi-bin/erle.cgi');

Comment: В общем Вы где-то содрали код, но не знаете как он работает, я правильно понял?

Comment: Как работает код для подгрузки баннера я понимаю. Вопрос совсем в другом. при обычной загрузке страницы баннер загружается. Но возникают проблемы, когда ajax`ом подгружаются новости среди которых содержится данный код. Мне нужно знать уместно ли подобное использование данного кода?